# n_jobs=-1 not using 100% of CPU

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am using [Sequential Feature Selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SequentialFeatureSelector.html) on ~200 features. I have 8 physical cores (+8 virtual), number of jobs is set to -1, but it still doesnt use 100% of CPU power, instead it uses 8%. How can I make it use 100%?

Comment: please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! at a minimum, it seems required to see the exact arguments to `SequentialFeatureSelector()` and if you see the problem when you call `.fit()` or before .. additionally, how your libraries were installed (ie. pip, anaconda, etc.) and if you're relying on joblib or [other parallelism features](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/computing/parallelism.html), what operating system you're using (ie. something with poor Python/C support like Windows), and how specifically you're accounting for CPU use would help!